# Error 3251 when setting record source for subform

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I've been having this error where I am unable to set the record source for a subform.

Just a bit of background, the form in question is structured as such: frm1View is my unbound main form which contains 2 subforms, subfrm1Particulars and subfrm1Datasheet. The issue is with subfrm1Particulars, which itself contains 2 subforms in a tab control.

I am attempting to change the recordsource of my subform in subfrm1Particulars dynamically, based on the records found in the other subform (one sub form displays courses completed and the other displays courses scheduled; the idea is to remove scheduled courses they have already completed from that sub form view).

I am using the following code to do this dynamic recordsource change. The code is contained in subfrm1Particulars(which contains subfrmScheduledCourses)

```
strSQL = *blah blah blah where etc etc not like etc*
Me.subfrmScheduledCourses.Form.Recordsource= strSQL
```

I've checked numerous times, my subform control name is correct (although my subform shares the same name as the control, so maybe that's the issue). I have almost the exact same form configuration in another form, with the same code (i.e. the same recordsource and SQL statements and method of assigning recordsource) and it works perfectly, so I can't tell why this isn't working.

It gives me an error 3251. I'm running this in the On Enter event of the subform control (in both of my forms where this particular code appears).

Any help at all is much appreciated!!

Comment: Neither can we debug this. You are left with studying the difference between the working and the non-working form. Or simply recreate the offending form bit by bit.

Comment: What is error 3251?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to subform objects can be tricky, especially from other subforms. Try calling the object differently:

```
Forms!frm1View!subfrm1Particulars.Form!subfrmScheduledCourses.Form.RecordSource
```

What this does it begins referring to form objects by navigating from mainform to subform to the desired area.